# Formatted input in c++

Tags: c++, vector, user-input

hey, i'm a noob to c++ (and coding in general)
i'm looking for an easy way to take two doubles (at once) from the keyboard and store them in a struct i've created called "Point" and then ultimately store the Point into a vector of Points that's a member of a class (called "Polygon").
i know i could do it with a scanf but need to know how to do it with cin.

hope that makes sense.

thanks in advance

julz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
double d1,d2;
cin>>d1>>d2;
```

or you can directly read it into your structure variable as:

```
point p;
cin>>p.x>>p.y;
```

assuming your structure is defined something like:

```
struct point {
 double x;
 double y;
}
```

Comment: really? and does the input need to be separated by a comma or just a space?

Comment: Yeah, operator>> is your friend in C++.

Comment: @julz666: No, but it'll sure go a long way toward getting more answers in the future...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to overload >> so that it operates on your structure directly:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& stream, Point& p) {
        return stream >> p.x >> p.y;
    }
}
```

You return the stream so that you can chain inputs the same way you can with built in types: `cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3`. In this specific case, the operator could be a freestanding function, rather than a friend, but in general a friend is easier to work with.

[This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.10) provides a lot of useful details on this sort of thing.

Comment: yeah, i think that's what our lecturer was getting at. i'll do some work on that, thanks